# How to cast an object to a DOMElement?

Tags: javascript, object, dom, casting, element

i want to cast un object to a DOM object.

For example, i have this constructor :

```
function Input(type, id, name, value)
{
    this = document.createElement("input");
    ...
}
```

As you can see, i put in the body `this = document.createElement("input");` for attempting cast the Input object to DOMElement object, but it doesn't work.

(I know I can do `this.input = document.createElement("input");`, but i want absolutely to cast the only `this` to `document.createElement("input");`)

Have you a idea please ?

Thank you in advance, cordially

Comment: That `this` is read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you could try the following:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var Input = function(type, id, name, value){
        this.element = this.create();

        this.setType(type);
        this.setValue(value);
        this.setName(name);

        return this.element;
    };

    Input.prototype.create = function(){
        return document.createElement("input");
    };

    Input.prototype.setType = function(type){
        this.element.type = type;
    };

    Input.prototype.setValue = function(value){
        this.element.value = value;
    };

    Input.prototype.setName = function(name){
        this.element.name = name;
    };

    var newInput = new Input("text", "", "qwe", "qwe");

    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newInput);

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code is what I look for !!!

I see in your code that i forgot the `return this.element` line

Now with `return this.element` line, alert(newInput); return exactly [object HTMLInputElement], it's what i want. 

So it's solved, and thank you again

Answer (score 0):

What about checking out this, it might give you an idea aobut how to go about it

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_createelement2